# Creating NSPredicate dynamically by setting the key programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

Why does the former of following snippets work while not the latter ?

**Snippet 1**

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(coin_unique == %@)", [NSNumber numberWithInt:species]];
```

**Snippet 2**

```
// Does NOT Work
NSString *predicateText = @"coin_unique";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%@ == %@)", predicateText, [NSNumber numberWithInt:species]];
```

I have to dynamically create predicate depending upon the argument received in my method.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`coin_unique` is a key, so it needs the `%K` format specifier:

```
NSString *predicateText = @"coin_unique";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K == %@)", predicateText, [NSNumber numberWithInt:species]];
```

The format syntax is described quite well [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html).

Answer (score 0):

I got the following error even though my NSPredicate was formatted correctly.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Insufficient arguments for conversion characters specified in format string.' site:stackoverflow.com
```

Like a fool I forgot to pass a second argument to the predicate format (because there were two `%@`). I.e. `NSPredicate(format:predicateFormat,argumentArray:[Date()])` has only one element in the array when it needs to be two: `[Date(), Date()]`